# Press button while looping a mouseclick

Tags: autohotkey

I wanted to create an old school runescape AHK, its 1 tick karambwan cooking, wherein I need to hold the space button then click back and forth from point a to point b.

My problem is the press key down is not working whenever the loop started

```
i := 0
Send {space down} ;Holds the space button 
loop {
    i++
    RandomBezier(0, 0, xInv25, yInv25, "T325 RO") ; Move and click point a
    click
    RandomBezier(0, 0, xAltar, yAltar, "T325 RO") ; Move and click point b
    click

    if (i > 25) {
        break
    }
}

;Send {space Up}
exitapp
```